# Unity c# ссылка

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d

Есть массив

```
public Item[] inventory;
```

К примеру я заполню

```
inventory[0] = new Item(...);
```

И как сделать чтоб элементы к примеру `1,4,6` могли изменяться вместе с нулевым элементом, к примеру поменял значение в нулевом элементе и в `1,4,6` значения тоже изменились.

Comment: Ну, например, пусть нулевой элемент имеет ссылки на тех,  кого он должен менять, и меняет их.

Comment: Что представляет из себя Item? И как должны меняться зависимые элементы?

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас для  `1, 4, 6` используется один и тот же класс `Item` то достаточно вносить изменения в этот элемент и они будут отображаться во всех остальных элементах. Если же вам нужно делать связанное изменение у разных элементов, то выход только делать отдельный механизм учитывающий связи между элементами и внесение изменений обрабатывать самостоятельно.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу,то просто

1. Создать класс

   class Someclass{ 
             // наш элемент
             var item;
            // массив(лучше список) хранящий номера ячеек,которые нужно изменить
             var[] refs;

   ```
    void someFunction(var item, var[] refs)
    {
      // здесь можем в цикле менять значения в массиве
    }
   }
   ```

2.Не пишем класс и просто меняем значения в цикле так же как и выше